# Get ID of object in external list of events in Fullcalendar v4

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a issue with fullcalendar v4. I am trying for days to get the id of an object declared in an external list as follows but no luck.

```
$(this).data('event', {
id: 2,
title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
classNames: [$(this).data('color')],
description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor eius mod tempor labore'
});
```

In the calendar:

```
var Draggable   = FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable;

        new Draggable(containerEl, {
            itemSelector: '.fc-draggable-handle',
            eventData: function(eventEl) {

                return $(eventEl).data('event');

            }   
        });
```

Then trying to retrieve the data on drop or eventReceive :

```
eventReceive: function(event, view) {
                alert("Dropped event: " + event);  // any data linked to the dropped event 

                var datax = $(this).data('event');

                console.log(datax);

            },    

            drop: function(arg) {

                console.log(arg.draggedEl);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#kt_calendar_external_events_remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(arg.draggedEl).remove();
                }
            },
```

Comment: anybody?? I am using this example: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: How can I get the object data ? id , title etc

Comment: found the solution for anybody that has the same problem.      eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
    console.log('eventReceive', event);
   },

Comment: if you found the solution then please add it as an Answer, below. Then people can upvote it if they like it... :-)

Comment: I did in my last comment

Comment: Yes but that was a **comment**. I'm suggesting you add it as a proper **answer**, then people can vote on it (and it will show in Google results etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found using eventReceive:

```
eventReceive: function(event) {
// called when a proper external event is dropped
console.log('eventReceive', event);
},
```